# How do I search for vertical (portrait) videos in the iOS Photos app?

Tags: ios, photos

Is there something I can type in the search bar to search for “vertical” (portrait orientation) videos in my iCloud Photo Library on iOS 16?

If not, is there another way to do this on macOS or iOS? I could use the command line if necessary but ideally looking for a GUI-based solution.